# Import csv using WebService

Tags: php, xml, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am currently importing .csv files (products, clients ...) by creating my own scripts, but I have read that it is possible to import via WebService, but unfortunately there is no information in net.

Could someone guide me on the subject?

Its that possible? How can i do?

Thank you!

I am currently using this script, and i want to do the same using WebService:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$employee = new Employee(1);
$context->employee = $employee;


function loadProductsPost() {

    $_POST = array (
        'tab' => 'AdminImport',
        'forceIDs' => '0',
        'skip' => '1',
        'csv' => 'productos.csv',
        'entity' => '1',
        'separator' => ';',
        'multiple_value_separator' => ',',
        'iso_lang' => 'es',
        'convert' => '',
        'import' => 'Importar datos csv',
        'type_value' => array(
            0 => 'id',
            1 => 'active',
            2 => 'no', //revisar
            3 => 'category',
            4 => 'price_tex',
            5 => 'id_tax_rules_group',
            6 => 'on_sale',
            7 => 'reduction_price',
            8 => 'reduction_percent',
            9 => 'reduction_from',
            10 => 'reduction_to',
            11 => 'reference',
            12 => 'supplier_reference',
            13 => 'supplier',
            14 => 'ean13',
            15 => 'height',
            16 => 'width',
            17 => 'depth',
            18 => 'weight',
            19 => 'quantity',
            20 => 'no',
            21 => 'minimal_quantity',
            22 => 'no',
            23 => 'no',
            24 => 'description',
            25 => 'no',
            26 => 'no',
            27 => 'no',
            28 => 'meta_title',
            29 => 'no',
            30 => 'no',
            31 => 'no',
            32 => 'image',
            33 => 'customizable',
            34 => 'visibility',
            35 => 'delivery_time',
            36 => 'features',
            37 => 'no',
            38 => 'no',
            39 => 'no',
            40 => 'no',
            41 => 'manufacturer',


        ),
    );
}


$import = New AdminImportController();
loadProductsPost();
$import->productImport();
```